# Set all options-tags to "disabled" when they match with array value (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I struggle a bit with a problem where I have to use two for loops (that's my approach at least), to compare data with an array. I'll try to keep it short:

I have an array `var excludeTimes = ["00:00", "00:45", "02:30", "14:15"] etc.`

and an `<select>` element with some `<option>` elements

```
<select id="Times">
        <option value="--:--">--:--</option>
        <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
        <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
        <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
        <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
etc.
</select>
```

Now, I want to compare the values in my `excludeTimes` array with the values of my `<option>` tags in `<select>`.

If they match, add the attribute "disabled" to the matched

```
function notSelectableTimes() {
  const excludeTimes = ["00:00", "00:45", "02:30", "14:15"] 
  const e = $("#Times>option").map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get();
  const ee = e.slice(1);

    for(i = 0; i < excludeTimes.length; i++) {

      const find = $.inArray( excludeTimes[i], ee);

      for(j = 0; j < ee.length; j++) {

        if( ee[j] === excludeTimes[i]) {
          console.log(`No bookings at ${ee[j]}!`);
          console.log(ee[j]);
          console.log(find);
        }
      }
    }
}

notSelectableTimes();
```

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the `attr()`ibute of disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route you're taking is a bit convoluted in my opinion. You loop through the options to map them to their values, then compare them to the array, and then hypothetically would need to *re-lookup the options by value to then disable them*.

The last step is the portion you're missing, but rather than complete that route, I'd prefer to propose an alternative. You're already looping through the options to `.map()` them - why not just compare the values in that loop instead?

The following loops through each `<option>` in `#Times` and sets its `disabled` attribute based on the presence of the option's value in the `excludeTimes` array.

```js
const excludeTimes = ["00:00", "00:45", "02:30", "14:15"];

$("#Times > option").attr("disabled", function() { //For each <option> in #Times
  return excludeTimes.includes($(this).val());     //Disable if value in excludeTimes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Times">
  <option value="--:--">--:--</option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I know my code was pretty inefficient and bloated. But yours is so clean, short and easy to understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you need to add a line as below 
$('#Times option[value="'+ee[j]+'"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            notSelectableTimes();
        });
        function notSelectableTimes() {
            const excludeTimes = ["00:00", "00:45", "02:30", "14:15"] 
            const e = $("#Times>option").map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get();
            const ee = e.slice(1);

            for(i = 0; i < excludeTimes.length; i++) {
                const find = $.inArray( excludeTimes[i], ee);
                for(j = 0; j < ee.length; j++) {
                    if( ee[j] === excludeTimes[i]) {
                        $('#Times option[value="'+ee[j]+'"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        console.log(`No bookings at ${ee[j]}!`);
                        console.log(ee[j]);
                        console.log(find);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too. It's adapt to my own code, that's cool. but I'll take the solution from Typer above.

Comment: @DamirLucic If above satisfies your question/doubt, can you please mark this as answer and give a thumbs up? So I can get points :)